# gammu-smsd sends sms only on startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, gammu

I run `gammu-smsd`:

```
# gammu-smsd
Log filename is "/var/log/gammu-smsd.log"
```

next I send sms via `gammu-smsd-inject`:

```
# echo sms bla bla bla | gammu-smsd-inject TEXT 123456789
gammu-smsd-inject[2050]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
gammu-smsd-inject[2050]: Created outbox message OUTC20151124_121117_00_796996999_sms0.smsbackup
Written message with ID /var/spool/gammu/outbox/OUTC20151124_121117_00_796996999_sms0.smsbackup
```

and..... 1 minute, 5 minites, 15 minutes and nothing.
So I interrupt `gammu-smsd` by `^\` and start it again:

```
# gammu-smsd
Log filename is "/var/log/gammu-smsd.log"
```

And now I have in `/var/log/gammu-smsd.log`:

```
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:07 gammu-smsd[2074]: Warning: No PIN code in /etc/gammu-smsdrc file
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:07 gammu-smsd[2074]: Created POSIX RW shared memory at 0xb6fcc000
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:07 gammu-smsd[2074]: Starting phone communication...
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:17 gammu-smsd[2074]: Read 1 messages
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:18 gammu-smsd[2074]: Message without SMSC, assuming you want to use the one from phone
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:19 gammu-smsd[2074]: Transmitted OUTC20151124_121117_00_123456789_sms0.smsbackup (total: 1) to 123456789, message reference 0x1b
Tue 2015/11/24 12:17:25 gammu-smsd[2074]: Read 1 messages
```

My configuration `/etc/gammu-smsdrc`:

```
# Configuration file for Gammu SMS Daemon

# Gammu library configuration, see gammurc(5)
[gammu]
port = /dev/huawei
model = at
connection = at19200
synchronizetime = yes

# SMSD configuration, see gammu-smsdrc(5)
[smsd]
service = files
logfile = /var/log/gammu-smsd.log
#debuglevel = 255
commtimeout = 10
sendtimeout = 20
deliveryreport = log
transmitformat = auto

# Paths where messages are stored
inboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/inbox/
outboxpath = /var/spool/gammu/outbox/
sentsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/sent/
errorsmspath = /var/spool/gammu/error/
```

So what am I doing wrong?

--- EDIT ---
I have removed `gammu` installed via `apt-get`, downloaded newest gammu from website `wammu.eu` and I compiled like in instruction. So now:

```
# gammu version
[Gammu version 1.36.6]
...
```

And

```
# gammu-detect
; Configuration file generated by gammu-detect.
; Please check The Gammu Manual for more information.

[gammu]
device = /dev/ttyUSB0
name = Phone on USB serial port HUAWEI_MOBILE HUAWEI_MOBILE
connection = at

[gammu1]
device = /dev/ttyUSB1
name = Phone on USB serial port HUAWEI_MOBILE HUAWEI_MOBILE
connection = at

opening socket: Nie ma takiego urządzenia
```

Where `/dev/huawei` is created by `ln -s /dev/ttyUSB0`

Now I typed `gammu identify` to check my device and after 1 hour I interrupted it because it waiting for something - i don't know for what.
Bellow is backtrac from gdb:

```
# gdb --args gammu --identify
GNU gdb (Raspbian 7.7.1+dfsg-5) 7.7.1
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from gammu...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /usr/local/bin/gammu --identify
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".
^C
Program received signal SIGINT, Interrupt.
0xb6d674ec in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
81      ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S: Nie ma takiego pliku ani katalogu.
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6d674ec in select () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:81
#1  0xb6f32968 in serial_read () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#2  0xb6e95c8c in GSM_ReadDevice () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#3  0xb6e95dcc in GSM_WaitForOnce () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#4  0xb6e95ef0 in GSM_WaitFor () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#5  0xb6edda2c in ATGEN_Initialise () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#6  0xb6e94f20 in GSM_TryGetModel () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#7  0xb6e95518 in GSM_InitConnection_Log () from /usr/local/lib/libGammu.so.7
#8  0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: What Gammu version do you use? Can you also increase debug level and include log messages from the time when nothing is sent?

Comment: I installed `gammu` on my Raspberry PI via `apt-get`. `gammu version` returns me `Gammu version 1.33.0 built 08:52:37 on Aug 14 2013 using GCC 4.6`. Hmm, I tought Raspbian have newer version. I'll try maunlly install nevest version of `gammu` and I'll check my issue again.

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread you need to use the /dev/serial/by-id/ path to the USB device.

e.g. port = /dev/serial/by-id/usb-Standard_USB_USB_2.0-if01

See http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.drivers.gammu/9719

Comment: Hi, unfortunatelly I hadn't enough patience and I replaced firmware in my USB modem to HiLink and I have internet  connection automatic and I'm sending sms by `curl` command as service on HiLink modem.
BTW thanks for reply!